# find time in c# by use array of byte

Tags: c#

program in c# find time :

```
byte []a = new byte {224,198,23,200};
Console.WriteLine( "time  {0} " ,BitConverter.ToInt32(a,0));
```

output: -939765856

what wrong in program ,i use `Convert.ToDateTime` but not has correct output

Comment: Where you got those values?

Comment: aside from not compiling, this doesn't really make sense

Comment: This snippet doesn't compile. Please provide a working reproducible example. You also need to edit and clarify your question. Please provide more details, what you are trying to do, the problems faced ect.

Comment: What value did you expect the BitConverter to create? Also your sample is missing `[]` after new byte. e.g. `new byte[] {224,198,23,200}`

Comment: What is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: This would be almost fascinating, if it made any sense.

Comment: There are a bunch of common ways to represent a date. You'll need to specify which...

Comment: We're looking at those arbitary numbers more than 10 minutes, we can't find any clue. How do you think `Convert.ToDateTime` knows about it?

Comment: i want to print correct time in second and minute or date in year month....not time = -939765856

Comment: result -939765856 not correct

Comment: @user2839704 How can you tell?

Comment: If I give you the "date" 837, would that make sense? 837 of what? Bananas? Days? 837 days since when? You need to be more specific about what your data means..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
byte[] a = new byte[] {224,198,23,200};
DateTime.FromBinary(BitConverter.ToInt16(a, 0))
```

6:59:59 of year 01

Comment: ok, this correct method

Comment: Plus 1 for decrypting the question! The answer was the easy part.

Comment: but...what does it mean.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the program it is working as programmed.  You didn't mention what value you were expecting.  I suspect you have your byte order wrong, what you have coded does this:

```
        byte[] a = new byte[] {224,198,23,200};
        Int32 x = (200 << 24) + (23 << 16) + (198 << 8) + 224;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", x);
```

Is that what you wanted ?

Comment: no, i want to print correct time in second and minute or date in year month....

Comment: im so damn interested in what the right date of `new byte {224,198,23,200};` is.  Please tell us

Comment: Awesome! Could you please put some details about your magic?